# Convert update from mysql to oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-update

Can anyone tell me how I can convert something like this in MySQL to Oracle?

```
Update table1 t1
    inner join table t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
    left join table t3 on t2.id = t3.t2_id
set 
    t1.some_table = 'some_value',
    t2.some_table = 'some_value',
    t3.some_table = 'some_value'
    where t1.id = somevalue
```

Comment: Does that work in MySQL?  What are `t2` & `t3`?

Comment: You cannot update three tables in one statement in Oracle.  You need three separate `update` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle (and most databases), you need three separate statements.  I imagine something like this:

```
update t1
    set t1.some_table = 'somevalue'
    where t1.id = somevalue;

update t2
    set t2.some_table = 'somevalue'
    where t2.t1_id = somevalue;

update t3
    set t3.some_table = 'somevalue'
    where exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.t1_id = somevalue and t3.t2_id = t2.id) ;
```

If you are using the `join`s for additional filtering, this might not be exactly right, but the structure is correct.  Use the `where` clause for filtering.

And, you might want to wrap all these in a single transaction, so either all succeed or all fail.